# Why cannot I ReDim an array with index of LongPtr or LongLong in Excel 2016 VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am used to use the following code on Excel 2010 (Windows 7 64-bit), and It works good.

```
Sub code_on_2010()
  Dim i As Long

  i = InputBox("input integer number")
  ReDim a(i) As Variant
  '....
End Sub
```

Recently, I upgrade my PC to Windows 10(64-bit) and Excel 2016(64-bit).  As I know the new type name for 64-bit Long integer type, I rewrite my code as below:

```
Sub code_on_2016_with_LongPtr()
  Dim i As LongPtr

  i = InputBox("input integer number")
  ReDim a(i) As Variant
  '...
End Sub
```

It returns a `Type mismatch (Error 13)` Error.

Even I replace the LongPtr with LongLong (as below), it returns `Type mismatch` error, too.

```
Sub code_on_2016_with_LongLong()
  Dim i As LongLong

  i = InputBox("input integer number")
  ReDim a(i) As Variant
  '...
End Sub
```

Could anybody tell me why I cannot ReDim an array with index of LongPtr or LongLong type in Excel 2016 VBA?

Comment: You first and second codes run fine on my system....Windows 10....Excel 365 Version 1802 Build 9029.2167

Comment: I don't think you can allocate that much memory anyway .. I get `Out of Memory` error at around `Dim a(2 ^ 27) As Variant`

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, Does Microsoft make some improvement only for Excel 365 instead of Excel 2016?  My version is also 1802 (build 9029.2167).   :(

Comment: @PaichengWu  I know of no difference.............see my answer............

Comment: Why are you using a LongPtr? That's only generally necessary for memory locations.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, Is your Excel 365 a 64-bit version?

Comment: @PaichengWu  How do I determine whether **32** or **64** bit version??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, In Excel, press `Alt+F` then `d`, then `a` shows the `About Microsoft Excel 2016` window.  On the first line of that window, you will see the 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: @PaichengWu  ***32 bit***

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, Maybe different Excel 2016 bit versions have different `LongPtr` default value.  For 32-bit, the `LongPtr` default is `Long`. For 64-bit, the default is `LongLong`.

Comment: Can you convert to `Long` with the *clng()* function?

Answer (score 2):

Excel 64 bits won't need LongPtr or LongLong in your code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub code_on_2010()
Dim i As Long 'declaring any other type won't speed up your code, and won't give a bigger range of possible numbers!
Dim h$
Dim a() 'basically says : a is a variable sized array of type variant
h = InputBox("input integer number")  'returns a string
if isnumeric(h) then i=clng(h)
ReDim a(i)
'....
End Sub
```